# asynchronous version of JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

Tags: node.js

```js
 var assert = require('assert');
 var parseJSON = require('json-parse-async');

 var contact = new Object();
 contact.firstname = "Jesper";
 contact.surname = "Aaberg";
 contact.phone = ["555-0100", "555-0120"];

 var contact2 = new Object();
 contact2.firstname = "JESPER";
 contact2.surname = "AABERG";
 contact2.phone = ["555-0100", "555-0120"];

 contact.toJSON = function(key) {
   var replacement = new Object();
   for (var val in this) {
     if (typeof(this[val]) === 'string')
       replacement[val] = this[val].toUpperCase();
     else
       replacement[val] = this[val]
   }
   return replacement;
 };

 var jsonText = JSON.stringify(contact);
 contact = JSON.parse(jsonText);
 console.log(contact);
 console.log(contact2);

 assert.deepEqual(contact, contact2, 'these two objects are the same');
```

What are the asynchronous equivalent functions of `JSON.parse`, `JSON.stringify` and `assert.deepEqual`? I am trying to create a race condition and non-deterministic behavior within the following code but I have not been able lto find non-blocking, asynchronous equivalents of the functions mentioned above.

Comment: Why do you want this? What problem you do you want to solve?

Comment: You can't magically wrap a synchronous function with something that actually make it asynchronous.  You can delay the execution with something like `setTimeout()`, but the code will run synchronous whenever it runs.  If you were to actually design for real synchronous execution (where the execution runs in the background while other JS runs), you'd have to completely rewrite it in native code in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

node.js does not have an actual asynchronous JSON parser built-in.  If you want something that will actually do the parsing outside the main node.js Javascript thread, then you would have to find a third party module that parses the JSON outside of the Javascript thread (e.g. in a native code thread or in some other process).  There are some modules in NPM that advertise themselves as asynchronous such as [async-json-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-json-parser) or [async-json-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-json-parse) or [json-parse-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-parse-async).  You would have to verify that whichever implementation you were interested in was truly an asynchronous implementation (your Javascript continues to run while the parsing happens in the background).

But, reading the detail in your question about the problem you're trying to solve, it doesn't sound like you actually need a parser that truly happens in the background.  To give you your ability to test what you're trying to test, it seems to me like you just need an indeterminate finish that allows other code to run before the parsing finishes.  That can be done by wrapping the synchronous `JSON.parse()` in a `setTimeout()` with a promise that has a random delay.  That will give some random amount of time for other code to run (to try to test for your race conditions).  That could be done like this:

```
JSON.parseAsyncRandom = function(str) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // use a random 0-10 second delay
        setTimeout(function() {
            try {
                resolve(JSON.parse(str));
            } catch(e) {
                 reject(e);
            }
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000));
    });
}


JSON.parseAsyncRandom(str).then(function(obj) {
    // process obj here
}, function(err) {
    // handle err here
});
```

Note: This is not true asynchronous execution.  It's an asynchronous result (in that it arrives some random time later and other code will run before the result arrives), but true asynchronous execution happens in the background in parallel with other JS running and this isn't quite that.  But, given your comment that you just want variable and asynchronous results for testing purposes, this should do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced this problem myself, so I decided to create a [library](https://github.com/federico-terzi/raji) to handle JSON parsing in a *really* asynchronous way.

The idea behind it is to divide the parsing process into chunks, and then run each separately in the event loop so that other events (user interactions, etc) can still be evaluated within a few milliseconds, keeping the UI interactive.

If you are interested, the library it's called RAJI and you can find it here: https://github.com/federico-terzi/raji

After installing RAJI, you can then convert your synchronous `JSON.parse` calls into async `raji.parse` calls, such as:

```js
const object = await parse(payload);
```

These calls won't block the UI

Comment: That's not "*really* asynchronous", quite the opposite.

Answer (score -3):

You can use 'bluebird', like this example to convert calling function to promise.

I write code below using javascript es6.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')

function stringifyPromise(jsonText) {
   return Promise.try(() => JSON.stringify(jsonText))
}

function parsePromise(str) {
   return Promise.try(() => JSON.parse(str))
}

stringifyPromise(contact)
  .then(jsonText => parsePromise(jsonText))
  .then(contact => {
    assert.deepEqual(contact, contact2, 'these two objects are the same')
  })
})
```

Comment: This would still not make JSON.stringify async - though it will call it from within async code

Comment: for research purposes, I am trying to create a situation in which I am capitalizing my JSON object asynchronously by calling the function "function(key)" shown above and then I would like to convert it back to an object. After that, I would like to call asset.deepEqual to check whether the two objects contact and contact2 are equal. I am just trying to have a subject for research purposes that demonstrates that things do not execute in order. How can I modify the above code such that I get an error message telling me that the two objects are not equal even though they are?

Comment: @slebetman, 

is this way solved your issue?

function stringifyPromise(jsonText) {
   return Promise.try(() => JSON.stringify(jsonText))
}

and you call stringifyPromise() instead of calling JSON.stringify() to get promise version of JSON.stringify()

Comment: @AlongkornChetasumon: You can get a promise version of JSON.stringify but that promise version will be synchronous, not asynchronous.

Comment: OK, i see. Thanks ^_^